# Need Assistance with collecting O365 Audit Logs with function app and directing them to Event Hub

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

I've been working on a project involving eventhub, function apps and O365 logs, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock. I'm using the Azure-Sentinel GitHub repository (link: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/tree/master/DataConnectors/O365%20Data) to collect Audit.General and DLP.ALL Activity Logs from O365, and currently, these logs are sent to Log Analytics/Sentinel.

However, I want to redirect these logs to Event Hub instead of Log Analytics. I've been stuck on this for a week now, and as someone who's new to working with function apps and coding, I'm finding it challenging. (Can share function app script if needed)

If anyone has experience with this or can provide guidance on the exact steps to follow, I would greatly appreciate it. I've also attempted to create a function app on my own and wrote a PowerShell script, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

My end goal is to have the logs reach Event Hub successfully, and then I want to analyze them using Data Explorer to confirm the data is reaching its destination.

Any help or advice you can provide would be invaluable to me at this point. Thanks in advance!

I've tried modifying the arm template mentioned in the github link. Analysed whether the code could could be modified in the same deployment (wasn't able to figure out).
Tried creating a function app from scratch, created a function app using time trigger function and wrote a PowerShell script, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be doing the trick, was able to see incoming requests in eventhub but no incoming messages recorded, and data explorer wasn't able to create a preview in Schema tab.

Comment: Enable [azure-diagnostics](https://medium.com/rupesh-tiwari/configuring-azure-diagnostics-log-8382743d68e7) and select Event Hub to log the data of the function in Event Hub.

Answer (score 0):

Refer these steps to collect O365 Audit Logs with a function app and direct them to Event Hub:

**Create an Azure Function App:**

- Create a new [Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-no-code?tabs=diagnostic-metrics) in the Azure portal.
- Select the appropriate consumption plan for your requirement.
  [image]

**Create an Event Hub sender function:**

Create a Timer Trigger Function according to the [**github Document**](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/tree/master/DataConnectors/O365%20Data#deploy-the-azure-function-app) you are referring to, That will create a custom table with O365 audit logs for you. Once the Table is added, Send that Table from your Functions App Diagnostic settings to Event Hub like below:-

- In Diagnostic settings send the Logs to Event Hub:-

[image]

[image]

[image]